# HTML video is not displaying

Tags: html, html5-video

I would like to run the code below but I'm getting a blank screen.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="vaction.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1, mp4a'">
    <source sr="vaction.webm" type="video/webm; codecs='vp8.0, vorbis'">
    <p>Video is running of family vacation.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Can you provide the console output?  It's possible that your URLs may be hitting 404 errors.

Comment: Also, I see a typo in your post that may or may not be in your actual code: the second <source> tag has "sr" instead of "src".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the c in src and you have a typo  in vacation, i am assuming it must be the same.

```
<source src="vacation.webm" type="video/webm; codecs='vp8.0, vorbis'">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have some typos here:
It should be **src** and not **sr** and **vacation** not **vaction**.

```
<source src="vacation.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1, mp4a'">
<source src="vacation.webm" type="video/webm; codecs='vp8.0, vorbis'">
```

Then, have you checked in the console, if the path is correct? Otherwise it will show an error there, and you need to correct it.

If this is the case, look where the videos are stored and if the name is correct. You have to keep in mind, that you need to start from your site root directory or begin the path with **./** if it's in the same folder as the file where you need it.